How to transpose dataframe from long to wide
How can I transpose this dataframe:



ID
DATE
BALANCE




1
2024-11
1000


1
2024-12
900


2
2024-11
1100


2
2024-12
800



to this:



ID
2024-11
2024-12




1
1000
900


2
1100
800




pivot_wider(df, id_cols = ID, names_from = DATE, values_from = BALANCE)
